# Prevent JS orientationchange events in Android WebView with locked orientation

Tags: javascript, android, android-webview, dom-events, orientation-changes

### Basically:

Is it possible to prevent specific `window` events from firing within `JavaScript` running inside a `WebView`? Specifically I want to prevent `window.orientationchange` events being fired.

(Alternatively is there any way to be absolutely certain I am inside a `WebView` and not in a normal Chrome/built-in browser window without overriding the User-Agent?)

### In detail:

I've been tasked with embedding an existing web application inside a basic `WebView` container on Android. The web app does not support portrait configurations, or browsers resized into a portrait aspect-ratio.

To fix that, there is a `window.orientationchange` handler in the `JavaScript` to detect this and display an error message if necessary.

For user-experience, we have the following Activity XML to prevent the user changing the orientation:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.example.my-stackoverflow-app"
    android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|screenSize"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Black.NoTitleBar.Fullscreen"
    android:screenOrientation="landscape">
```

This works perfectly. The trouble is, `orientationchange` events get fired when pausing/resuming the Activity.

Since the Home Screen is portrait the `window.orientationchange` handler is detecting this *before* the Activity re-orients itself and is locking me out of the app.

Naturally enough, a `setTimeout` call fixes this, but there is a rather large sky-scraper outside my window which I will be visiting before resorting to a `setTimeout` fix.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can't modify the user agent of your webview app, you could load a javascript: URL from your WebView app that sets a flag to say you are running inside a WebView, then check that flag when the event fires in JS... you'd need to re-inject this JS every time a new page loads. You could also add a JavaScript interface object from your java; and test for it's presence to detect the WebView. Once you add a JS interface object, it will be maintained automatically across page loads, but be careful (see docs for warnings[1])

Out of curiosity, why are you unable to override the  UA?

[1] http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#addJavascriptInterface(java.lang.Object, java.lang.String)

Comment: Shoot I completely forgot about this question. Unfortunately, I was proven to be an idiot after we realised I was testing this on my phone when the app will only be deployed to tablets. We couldn't find a solution to this beyond the answer you suggested so I'll mark this as accepted, since there doesn't seem to be any way around it.